# Rename a subset of files in a directory

Tags: bash

I have many hundreds of thousands of files in a directory. These files are named as follows:

```
left-00001.tiff
left-00002.tiff
...
left-99999.tiff
left-100000.tiff
...
left-245000.tiff
```

I would like to rename the files as follows:

```
left-000001.tiff
...
left-099999.tiff
...
left-245000.tiff
```

I found elegant solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417979/batch-rename-sequential-files-by-padding-with-zeroes).

This solution implements a bash script called `zeropad.sh`. the bash is coded as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=`expr match "$1" '[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*'`
paddednum=`printf "%06d" $num`
echo ${1/$num/$paddednum}
```

and can be applied iteratively using `for loop` as follows:

```
for i in *.tiff;do mv $i `./zeropad.sh $i`; done
```

However, this solution takes a very long time because it does much unnecessary work renaming all the files which are already properly padded. `i.e. as %06d type numbers`. For my own purposes this is solution is very slow.

I have two questions:

1- How can I modify the iterator to only apply `zeropad.sh` on files which need to be zero padded?

2- How can I use the command `touch` in a `for loop` to generate test data? It is crucial to verify that this script works before I apply it on the original data.

Comment: It is slow because you are calling your shell script for every file. It would be quicker if you did the looping and renaming in the same script.

Comment: Posting as comment because question asks for `bash`, but I think Python is a better fit: `from pathlib import Path; for f in Path().glob('left-?????.tiff'): f.rename(f.name.replace('-', '-0'))` Note that `touch left-{00001..99999}.tiff` can be used to quickly generate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bulk of the time spent by your loop is probably in calling your `zeropad.sh` script.

Instead, do it all in one script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in left-*.tiff; do
    if [[ "$filename" =~ ^left-0*([1-9]?[0-9]+)\.tiff$ ]]; then
        num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        newname="left-$( printf '%06d' "$num" ).tiff"
        if [ "$filename" != "$newname" ] && [ ! -e "$newname" ]; then
            echo mv "$filename" "$newname"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you have verified that the script is doing the correct thing.

Comment: works great and is easiest for me to understand @kusalananda. Thanks very much.

Comment: Still forks a `mv(1)` for each `rename(2)` system call it needs to make; a dedicated renaming tool like the [perl `rename` script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327613/rename-multiple-files-from-command-line/14327650#14327650), available as `prename` on some distros.  Or for some patterns, [`mmv -n '*-foo*' '#1-bar#2`   *.tiff` is nice and easier to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417916/how-to-do-a-mass-rename/418122#418122).  I find it worth installing.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I usually do it (manually on the shell):

```
rename left- left-0 left-?.png    # for 0-9
rename left- left-0 left-??.png   # for 00-99
rename left- left-0 left-???.png  # for 000-999
# result left-0000.png - left-9999.png
```

This is easy to do in an interactive shell session... just repeat the last command with one additional `?` added.

However, with a large number of files, you'll eventually end up with a too long list of arguments. And obviously it's not the most efficient choice, as it ends up renaming the same file multiple times (left-1.png -> left-01.png -> left-001.png -> ...).

Also there are two flavors for `rename` about, one with perl regular expressions and one without. Depending on distro you end up with `rename.ul` or `perl-rename` or other names for them. Basically it renders any script using the `rename` command unportable since you never know what to expect.

I'm using the the util-linux rename and your question is actually one of their examples, from the man page:

> ```
> EXAMPLES
>
> Given the files foo1, ..., foo9, foo10, ..., foo278, the commands
>
>     rename foo foo00 foo?
>     rename foo foo0 foo??
>
> will turn them into foo001, ..., foo009, foo010, ..., foo278.
> ```

Which is the more efficient method (each file renamed only once) but you have to figure out the correct distribution of `000` vs `???` or you'll end up with a wrong result.

To me, the inefficient method is the more practical one, on an interactive shell, when dealing with a reasonable small set of files.

---

The advantage of `rename` over scripting it yourself is that it doesn't have to spawn one `mv` process for each file, or as in your case, a sub-script just to figure out a filename. It's not clear what has more overhead, the process spawning, or repeated renaming, and I'm too lazy to benchmark it.

Actually the answer you linked already contains the "optimal" solution at the very end... using perl-rename:

```
rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%04d",$&)/e' *.png
```

Well, one can argue about the regular expression, but the point is, it's possible to do it all in one go, without unnecessary `mv`, or spawning of processes. If you still need to improve on that, write a tool that reads directory contents directly instead of using shell globbing (which sorts, which is slow) and performs the renaming as needed.

Maybe that's actually the answer you linked to and maybe that's why you're getting downvoted. ;)

Answer (score 4):

What's costly is to fork so many processes and run so many commands for each file.

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/files # make mv builtin to speed things up
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(*-)(<->)(.tiff)' '$1${(l:6::0:)2}$3'
```

(remove `-n` when happy)

That's all with builtins, so doesn't fork any process nor execute any file.

Or with `perl`'s `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/\d+(?=\.tiff\z)/sprintf "%06d", $&/e' ./*[0-9].tiff
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, consider:

```
for i in left-?????.tiff left-????.tiff left-???.tiff left-??.tiff left-?.tiff ...`
```

If that generates too many files, then break it up into sections:

```
for i in left-?????.tiff ...`
```

...

```
for i in left-????.tiff ...`
```

...

The above works by using the `?` glob character to substitute any single character whenever it appears. Here, I've specifically requested 5, 4, 3, 2, and then 1 digits after the leading `left-`.

For the second part, one option is:

```
dir=$(mktemp)
cd "$dir"
for i in $(seq 10); do touch $(printf 'left-%05d.tiff' $((RANDOM % 10000))); done
```

Adjust the `seq 10` to generate more or fewer filenames. Adjust the `% 10000` to generate smaller or larger numbers. Note that bash's $RANDOM generates numbers between 0 and 32,767.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I will try this as soon as I'm back to my pc

Comment: Thakns jeff, I used the dummy data generator you suggested. The renaming script led to a generating too many files bug and I didn't really troubleshoot. Sorry I didn't accept it. @kusalanda's solution is just easier to understand with my limited unix knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You can rename all the files in parallel. Do the following trivial changes on the same slow code that you had provided in your question, as follows:

```
cd data_folder  # cd the folder where you put the *.tiff files
for i in *.tiff;do 
{
mv $i `./zeropad.sh $i`;
}&
```

This will rename all the files at once. Please be aware that you must have enough memory resources on your workstation before you run this code inside the folder that contain the `*.tiff` files. No enough memory resources may lead to memory crash. But given that the process is only renaming files you should be fine!

In order to take into acccount memory resources on your workstation. Save the following code in a file called `code`, give it permissions then run it:

```
mem=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }' | grep Memory | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d "()%MB" | cut -d / -f 2  )

for i in *.tiff;do 
{
mv $i `./zeropad.sh $i`;
}&

if [ $mem -lt 100000 ] 
 then 
   if  (( "$i" % 75 == 0 ))
    then 
      sleep 4
   fi
 fi
if [ $mem -gt 100000 ] 
 then 
   if  (( "$i" % 300 == 0 ))
    then 
      sleep 3
   fi
 fi
done
```

When you run `code`, it will check memory resources on your workstation using the variable `mem`. If memory is less `100000MB`, then it will rename `75 files` at once. If memory resources are more than `100000MB`, then it will rename up to `300 files` at once. However, you can adjust all the variables as you want.

Comment: Hi TNT: I did not try this because @Kusalananda's solution was simply easier for me to understand with limited knowledge. However, how much memory would this require? Does it actually hold the files in RAM? The folder of files is of the order of ~500GB

Comment: @kevinkayaks. 500GB is to much. Please see my edits. I had updated the code. Now it will sense how much memory resources are available and then it will rename the files accordingly. You can adjust the numbers in the code as you want!

Comment: @kevinkayaks: Renaming a file within the same directory (or on the same filesystem) doesn't require touch the file's data *at all*.  Renaming a 1TB file is as fast as renaming an empty file; the `rename(2)` system call just has to modify directory entries (and update the `ctime` in the file's own inode).  The memory consumption here doesn't come from filesize, it just comes from the couple MB of RAM for `mv`, but mostly the `zeropad.sh` in parallel many times.  **This doesn't optimize away the `bash` startup cost of running `zeropad.sh` once per file.**

Answer (score 1):

I love Perl one-liners:

```
ls left-*.tiff | perl -ne 'if(m/(\S+)-(\d+).tiff/){chomp;printf "mv $_ left-%06d.tiff\n", $2}' | bash
```

PS, make sure to double check the output before piping into `bash`. Just to be safe.

Comment: perl has a `rename` function built-in.  Printing out `bash` commands is always going to be slower.  Or better, use the existing `rename` wrapper script like Stephane's answer.